# How to obtain the index of the max value of a column for each level of another column R

Tags: r

given a dataframe like this:

```
COUNTRY  CITIZENS  SURFACE

A        20000000   40
A        80000000   78
B        3000000    120
B        200000     27
C        10000000   56
A        5600000    20
C        10000000   30
B        2500000    20
```

I would like to subset the dataframe just with the rows corresponding to the max value of citizens for each country level.

I was able to obtain the max value of "citizens" for each level of country with dplyr and summarize, but I am not able to extract the corresponding surface  value for each max value.

Do you know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice` after grouping by 'COUNTRY'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
  slice(which.max(CITIZENS))
```

Or with `filter`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(COUNTRY) %>%
   filter(CITIZENS == max(CITIZENS))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[CITIZENS == max(CITIZENS)], COUNTRY]
```